# Programmatically slice a Pandas dataframe in place

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of dataframes that I am trying to slice and assign back to the original names. But I am finding that there is a namespace issue. Below is what I have.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(14,2), columns = list('XY'))
df_b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(14,2), columns = list('XY'))

mylist =[df_a, df_b]

def truncate_before(list_of_dfts, idx):
    for dfts in list_of_dfts:
        dfts = dfts[idx:]
        print(dfts.head)

truncate_before(mylist, 11)
print(df_a)
```

In the print statements within the truncate_before function, it shows 3 rows, corresponding to the 11th, 12th and 13th row. But the final print statement shows 0th to 13th rows.

So outside the function, it reverts back to the original dataframes. I was under the impression that Python passes arguments by reference. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `truncate_before`:

```
def truncate_before(list_of_dfts, idx):
    for dfts in list_of_dfts:
        dfts = dfts[idx:]
        print(dfts.head)
```

the `for-loop` creates a local variable `dfts` which references the DataFrames in `list_of_dfts`. But

```
        dfts = dfts[idx:]
```

*reassigns* a new value to `dfts`. It does not change the DataFrame in `list_of_dfts`.

See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) for a great explanation of how variable names bind to values, and what operations change values versus binding new values to variable names.

Here are a number of alternatives:

**Modify the list inplace**

```
def truncate_before(list_of_dfts, idx):
    list_of_dfts[:] = [dfts[idx:] for dfts in list_of_dfts]
    for dfts in list_of_dfts:
        print(dfts.head)
```

since assigning to `list_of_dfts[:]` (which calls `list_of_dfts.__setitem__`) changes the contents of `list_of_dfts` in-place.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(14,2), columns = list('XY'))
df_b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(14,2), columns = list('XY'))

mylist = [df_a, df_b]

def truncate_before(list_of_dfts, idx):
    list_of_dfts[:] = [dfts[idx:] for dfts in list_of_dfts]

print(mylist[0])
truncate_before(mylist, 11)
print(mylist[0])
```

shows `mylist[0]` has been truncated. Note that `df_a` still references the original DataFrame, however.

---

**Return the list and reassign `mylist` or `df_a, df_b` to the result**

Using return values may make it unnecessary to modify `mylist` in-place.

To *reassign* the global variables `df_a`, `df_b` to a new values, you could make
`truncate_before` return the list of DataFrames, and reassign `df_a` and `df_b`
to the returned value:

```
def truncate_before(list_of_dfts, idx):
    return [dfts[idx:] for dfts in list_of_dfts]

mylist = truncate_before(mylist, 11)   # or
# df_a, df_b = truncate_before(mylist, 11) # or
# mylist = df_a, df_b = truncate_before(mylist, 11)
```

But note that it is probably not good to access the DataFrames through both `mylist` and `df_a` and `df_b`, since as the example above shows, the values do not stay coordinated automagically. Using `mylist` should suffice.

---

**Use a DataFrame method with the inplace parameter, such as `df.drop`**

`dfts.drop` (with `inplace=True`) modifies `dfts` itself:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(14,2), columns = list('XY'))
df_b = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(14,2), columns = list('XY'))

mylist = [df_a, df_b]

def truncate_before(list_of_dfts, idx):
    for dfts in list_of_dfts:
        dfts.drop(dfts.index[:idx], inplace=True)

truncate_before(mylist, 11)
print(mylist[0])
print(df_a)
```

By modifying `dfts` inplace, both the values in `mylist` *and* `df_a` and `df_b`
get changed at the same time.

Note that `dfts.drop` drops rows based on index label value. So the above relies
(assumes) that `dfts.index` is unique. If `dfts.index` is not unique,
`dfts.drop` may more rows than `idx` rows. For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2], index=['A', 'A'])
df.drop(['A'], inplace=True)
```

drops *both* rows making `df` an empty DataFrame.

Note also this warning from Pandas' core developer regarding the use of `inplace`:

> My personal opinion: I never use in-place operations. The syntax is harder to
>     read and its does not offer any advantages.

This is probably because under the hood, `dfts.drop` creates a new dataframe and
then calls the `_update_inplace` private method to assign the new data to the
old DataFrame:

```
def _update_inplace(self, result, verify_is_copy=True):
    """
    replace self internals with result.
    ...
    """
    self._reset_cache()
    self._clear_item_cache()
    self._data = getattr(result,'_data',result)
    self._maybe_update_cacher(verify_is_copy=verify_is_copy)
```

Since the temporary `result` had to be created anyway, there is no memory or performance benefit of "in-place" operations over simple reassignment.

Comment: Ok, mylist was a construct to group together all the individual dataframes. Is there nothing else I can do in terms of the original dataframes? Of course, I could just do it one by one. df_a = df_a[idx:], etc. But a programmatic way would be nice. Let me finish reading the article you recommended.

Comment: `df.drop(..., inplace=True)` does modify `df` inplace, but due to the way inplace operations are implemented in Pandas, there is no real advantage to doing this over the more straight-forward reassignment to variable names. Personally I prefer functions that return values over functions that modify values, since with the former the assignment syntax makes it utterly clear what is getting modified.