# inplace version of DataFrame.head() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, indexing, in-place

Is there an inplace version of `df.head(max_rows)` in pandas?

I need to limit the number of rows in my dataframe when they are too many to be processed.

At the moment I am doing `df = df.head(10000000)` but I think this is memory inefficient.

Comment: I did not understand the point of this but `In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: pd.options.display.max_rows
Out[3]: 60
`

Comment: please look at the answer below, which is more cleaner in case  you want to hardcode the rows to be display which is pandas providing cleanely

Comment: probable duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876193/is-there-a-concise-way-to-show-all-rows-in-pandas-for-just-the-current-command?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for an *in place* operation:

```
n = 10000000
df.drop(df.index[n:], inplace=True)
```

But this may not help. As per [@unutbu's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35102908/programmatically-slice-a-pandas-dataframe-in-place#comment57927792_35103054):

> `df.drop(..., inplace=True)` does modify `df` inplace, but due to the
>   way `inplace` operations are implemented in Pandas, there is no real
>   advantage to doing this over the more straight-forward reassignment to
>   variable names. Personally I prefer functions that return values over
>   functions that modify values, since with the former the assignment
>   syntax makes it utterly clear what is getting modified.

This is explained further in [Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533110/9209546).

In addition, note this method will not work with duplicated indices.

Comment: also this approach does not work with duplicates indexes

Comment: @Donbeo, Correct, I'll add that as a disclaimer.

Comment: sorry do you have a reference explaining why inplace would work ?

Comment: sorry I was wondering if you can clarify/explain the statement `ut due to the way inplace operations are implemented in Pandas, there is no real advantage to doing`

Comment: @Donbeo, See link I've added